# IAM nested stack fails to complete due to undefined resource policies

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have created a nested IAM stack, which constists of 3 templates:
- iam-policies
- iam-roles
-iam user/groups

the masterstack template looks like this:

```
Resources:

Policies:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
        TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/iam/iam_policies.yaml

UserGroups:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
        TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/iam/iam_user_groups.yaml


Roles:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
        TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/iam/iam_roles.yaml
```

The policy ARNs are exported via Outputs section like:

```
Outputs:
  StackName:
   Description: Name of the Stack
   Value: !Ref AWS::StackName

  CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy:
    Description: ARN of the managed policy
    Value: !Ref CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy
```

in the Role template the policies ARNs are imported like

```
CodeBuildRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  RoleName: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-CodeBuildRole
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Action: 
        - 'sts:AssumeRole'
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service: 
          - codebuild.amazonaws.com
  Path: / 
  ManagedPolicyArns:
  - !GetAtt 
    - Policies
    - Outputs.CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy
```

But when I try create the stack, it fails saying the Roles stack cannot be created because

```
Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource Policies
```

How can I force the creation of the policies first so the second and third template can use the policies to create roles and user/ groups? Or is the issue elsewhere?

merci A

Answer (score 2):

Your question,

> How can I force the creation of the policies first so the second and
>   third template can use the policies to create roles and user/ groups?
>   Or is the issue elsewhere?

You can use "DependsOn" attribute. It automatically determines which resources in a template can be parallelized and **which have dependencies that require other operations to finish first**. You can use DependsOn to explicitly specify dependencies, which overrides the default parallelism and directs CloudFormation to operate on those resources in a specified order.

**In your case second and third template DependsOn Policies**

More details : [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html)

Answer (score -1):

The reason on why you aren't able to access the outputs is that, you haven't exposed the outputs for other stacks.

Update your Outputs with the data you want to export. Ref - [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) for the same.

Then, use the function Fn::ImportValue in the dependent stacks to consume the required data. Ref - [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) for the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: merci, but i thought using export/ ImportValue is not necessary since it's a nested stack. it of course works if I cross-reference the values using export/ import. but i want them in a nested stack.